# SAXException: Content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: java, xml, exception

This is driving me crazy. I have used this bit of code for lots of different projects but this is the first time it's given me this type of error. This is the whole XML file:

```
  <layers>
    <layer name="Layer 1" h="400" w="272" z="0" y="98" x="268"/>
    <layer name="Layer 0" h="355" w="600" z="0" y="287" x="631"/>
  </layers>
```

Here is the operative bit of code in my homebrew Xml class which uses the DocumentBuilderFactory to parse the Xml fed into it:

```
public static Xml parse(String xmlString)
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = null;
        //System.out.print(xmlString);
        try
        {
            doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                    new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            // Get root element...
            Node rootNode = (Element) doc.getDocumentElement();
            return getXmlFromNode(rootNode);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ParserConfigurationException in Xml.parse");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e)
        {
            System.out.println("SAXException in Xml.parse ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException in Xml.parse");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The context that I am using it is: school project to produce a Photoshop type image manipulation application. The file is being saved with the layers as .png and this xml file for the position, etc. of the layers in a .zip file. I don't know if the zipping is adding some mysterious extra characters or not.

I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that what you posted is indeed the content of your XML file? What does your debugger say about the content of `xmlString` variable? Do you perhaps have multiple root elements? You also might want to post the code which generates the content of `xmlString`.

Comment: Thanks for this question and answer. I agree with GenericJam - it's related to the buffer. By default, all the bytes are 0 (zero) and a call to 'zipFile.getInputStream(xmlZipFile).read(buffer)' will overwrite the first 'n' of these bytes. However the trailing 0-bytes will be considered as 'content' in the XML document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully this can be helpful to someone at some point. The fix that worked was just to use lastIndexOf() with substring. Here's the code in situ:

```
public void loadFile(File m_imageFile)
{
   try
   {
     ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(m_imageFile);

     ZipEntry xmlZipFile = zipFile.getEntry("xml");

     byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
     zipFile.getInputStream(xmlZipFile).read(buffer);
     String xmlString = new String(buffer);
     Xml xmlRoot = Xml.parse(xmlString.substring(0, xmlString.lastIndexOf('>')+1));
     for(List<Xml> iter = xmlRoot.getNestedXml(); iter != null; iter = iter.next())
     {
       String layerName = iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("name");
       m_view.getCanvasPanel().getLayers().add( 
           new Layer(ImageIO.read(zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry(layerName))), 
               Integer.valueOf(iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("x")),
               Integer.valueOf(iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("y")),
               Integer.valueOf(iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("w")),
               Integer.valueOf(iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("h")),
               Integer.valueOf(iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("z")),
               iter.element().getAttributes().getValueByName("name"))
        );
     }
     zipFile.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
   {
     System.out.println("FileNotFoundException in MainController.loadFile()");
     e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e)
   {
       System.out.println("IOException in MainController.loadFile()");
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

Thanks for all the people that contributed. I suspect the error was either introduced by the zip process or by using the byte[] buffer. Any further feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

If you look at that file in an editor, you'll see content (perhaps whitespace) following the end element e.g.

```
</layers>  <-- after here
```

It's worth dumping this out using a tool that will highlight whitespace chars e.g.

```
$ cat -v -e my.xml
```

will dump 'unprintable' characters.

Comment: I tried it using String.trim(), etc. to ensure that the ">" is the last character. The error message from the parser says that the error is in that position - the ">" itself.

Comment: @GenericJam trim() removes whitespace. If the trailing characters are not considered whitespace, this method will have no effect.

Comment: @Brain Agnew, I am getting the same error even if I return a simple JSP  as AJAX response with text "ABC" (with no leading and trailing spaces). Please suggest changes

Comment: I had the same issue and the parameters in `cat` did the charm for me. Try observing where is the last `$` that symbolizes the line end.

Answer (score 3):

I had some extra char at the end of XML, check the XML properly or do an online format of XML , which will throw error if XML is not proper. I used
[Online XML Formatter](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-formatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error in Sterling Integrator - when I looked at the file in a hex editor
it had about 5 extra lines of char(0), not space. No idea where they from, but this was precisely the issue, especially as I was basically doing a unity transform, so the xsl engine - in this case xalan - was obviously passing it through into the result. Removed extra rows after last close angle bracket, problem solved.